# The solar spectrum on the time domain

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, thermal-radiation, spectroscopy, signal-processing

This is the solar spectrum by wavelength:

[image]

By formula $c=f\lambda$, we can plot the solar spectrum over the frequency domain:
[image]

Then we can conduct inverse Fourier transform to transform the plot into the time domain:[image]

Here is my question: What does the solar spectrum over the time domain tell us about the sun light? Why does the solar spectrum on time domain behave as that?

Comment: You cannot do an inverse Fourier transform from only having the *amplitude* part of the frequency spectrum, but not its *phase* part.

Comment: The spectrum tells you about the temporal coherence length. The peak in your reconstruction of the time domain only happens because you didn't randomize the phases. It's an artifact.

Comment: @FlatterMann So how do we randomise the phases as you said? How to conduct this using python?

Comment: Python questions are off-limits on SE, but you basically multiply every one of your Fourier coefficients with a random complex number with magnitude 1.

Comment: @FlatterMann You mean I should multiply every element of the irradiance dataset defined on the time domain with a random complex number with magnitude 1, right?

Comment: Yes. What you will see is that the spike will go away and you will get a noise-like function, instead.

Comment: @FlatterMann As you instructed I randomised the phase. But how should we interpret the graph in terms of physics?

Comment: The graph is meaningless. What you would see if you would look at light with that resolution is not a random electromagnetic field. You would start seeing individual photons.

Comment: @FlatterMann Is it ok to say that the graph explains why the sunlight in short period does not change?

Comment: No. It isn't doing that, either.

Answer (score 2):

> By formula $c=f\lambda$, we can plot the solar spectrum over the frequency domain

Simply substituting $\lambda=c/f$ won't yield the correct frequency spectrum, because it's a spectral power density and must include the Jacobian of this transformation, so that integration over frequency of the new spectrum yielded the same total power as integration over wavelengths of the old spectrum.

> Then we can conduct inverse Fourier transform

Note that your spectrum is very crude: it has only a few hundred spectral points, not resolving many of the features. Thus, your time-domain signal will be limited in time.

But then, even if you get an extremely high-resolution spectrum of sunlight, you'll still have a problem: such a spectrum power density can belong to an infinite number of different time-domain signals, because power density is just a squared modulus of the actual spectrum of e.g. an electric field component.

Even worse, a real-life sunlight consists of time-limited wave packets emitted at random times with random phases and lengths. This means that measurements of time-domain signal don't tell you much more than what you'd get from the power spectrum.

> Why does the solar spectrum on time domain behave as that?

What you obtained (ignoring your wrong variable substitution) is the result of treating the power spectrum as complete complex-valued field spectrum. But it's not only the spectrum of the wrong quantity, but it's also too special case that isn't realistic. A bit more realistic result you could get if you

1. take a square root of the power density to get something more resembling field spectrum;
2. assign a random phase to each spectral point by multiplying them by $e^{i\alpha}$ with $\alpha$ being a new random number in $[0,2\pi)$ for each point of the spectrum.

Then you might get something, but it's going to be just a random signal with some limitations on how it can behave. So don't hold your breath expecting to see something exciting.

Comment: I think the main problem with his approach is that a physical power spectrum is not the magnitude squared of the Fourier transform of the time series. For one thing it does not satisfy the requirements of the sampling theorem. We don't know how each data point in that spectrum was actually taken (even though we can guess). The Fourier transform only produces reliable results if we have taken the data with proper sampling. I don't think we can explain that to him with his level of knowledge, though, can we?

Comment: @FlatterMann the physical transform is band limited for sure, but it's the least of the problems of the OP. And even though not each point was actually taken but rather most are interpolated, it will, as noted in my answer, only affect the time interval of validity of the recovered signal. The main problem is that phase information is completely lacking, so we just cannot get anything even resembling the original signal. As for the level of knowledge of the OP, this I cannot be sure of. If there's something we can explain more, the OP should tell us what.

Comment: I know. That, however, is the problem when you are talking about time domain/frequency domain transformations and the power spectrum. You aren't wrong in whatever you said, it just happens that the mathematical crux of the problem that renders the interpretation of this data difficult is sampling. That the phase information isn't there happens to be related to the fact that spectral data is not actually sampled, neither in the time nor the frequency domain. It's filtered and then integrated. You are correct, of course, that destroys the necessary information for the reconstruction.